# EF Core In-memory Database can't handle .Count on related table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I've run into a problem when using EF Core in memory databases, where parts of the query run doesn't work. But when the same query is run with an actual SQL database there isn't any errors.

This is the code where I experince problems with the in memory database.

```
var mappedFolders = await _dbContext.Folders.Include(f => f.SubFolders).Include(f => f.Files).Where(f => f.Deleted.HasValue == false).Select(f =>
    new Shared.Domain.Folder(
        f.UId,
        f.ParentFolder == null ? (Guid?)null : f.ParentFolder.UId,
        f.Name,
        f.Description,
        f.Files.Count
    ))
.ToListAsync();
```

The problem appears to be that when using in memory databases the line: f.Files.Count, can't execute correctly.

I've tried workign around this by resolving the query before I do the select, this works, but the performance is many times worse, and isn't really an option.

We are using EF Core version: 3.1.12

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: EF Core version please

Comment: We are using EF Core version 3.1.12.
Original post has also been updated.

Comment: [The in-memory database is for testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli). Which I think means: for internal EF tests or tests that need quick data for business logic unit tests. I've found the only true reliable way to test EF queries themselves is integration tests against the database brand that's used in production,  which usually isn't Sqlite. BTW, the `Includes` are redundant, they will be ignored because of the projection (`select new`).

Comment: The problem seems to be with the constructor call. If you replace it with "regular" object initialization (e.g. `new Shared.Domain.Folder { UId = f.UId, ... }`, it works as expected. Probably some bug in `InMemoryProvider`.